# N+1 Selects generete CommunicationsException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I have simple controller

```
@GetMapping("users")
List<User> getUsers() {
```

inside I have code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<1000;++i)
  userRepository.getOne(i);
```

after a few minutes sometimes I get:

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
```

but for 95% calls it works.

if I reduce the number of iterations:

```
for(int i = 0; i<100;++i)
      userRepository.getOne(i);
```

It always works.

my settings:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://test.dailyrazor.com:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
```

code is just to illustrate the problem, a real example comes from N+1 Selects

How can I prevent org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace ?

Comment: This sounds like your database closes the connection when it is open for to long, or causes to much load, or executes to many statements. A full stacktrace might proove this. You might want to talk to you dba.